# When a site fails private beta, how quickly are commitments reusable?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase, commitment-phase

If a site fails beta, can the commitments, particularly for those who otherwise succeeded in fulfilling commitments, how quickly can they recommit?  The faq doesn't seem very clear about this, and it's been over a day since Big Data closed and my commitment is not reusable yet.  If it is a long period of time, this ties up already very spartan commitment space for reasons of other people not helping out enough.  Here are some recommendations I could suggest for making this process easier:

1. For those who asked/answered at least ten questions, maybe the commitment should be reusable as soon as the decommissioning is announced (i.e. before the site actually terminates).
2. For those who did not (or did not even sign up), maybe the commitment should be non-reusable for longer.

Comment: It has now been over three days since the site was terminated and the commitment is not reusable yet, suggesting to me that it won't be reusable for a significant period of time :-P

Answer (score 5):

So no answer from moderators.  I  want to just note here that in this case it took around 4 days.  It might be worth mentioning this in the FAQ.